# search definition in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I am attempting to render a `search_failed` page in case a product is not found.

Line #4 shows an error.

Here's my code:

```
def search
    if (params[:search]).present?
        @products = Product.search(params[:search]) 
        unless @products = Product.search(params[:search]).!present?
            render 'search_failed'
        end

    else
        render 'search_failed'
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (you are calling the search twice in your example)

```
def search
    if (params[:search]).present?
        @products = Product.search(params[:search]) 
        if @products.empty?
            render 'search_failed'
        end

    else
        render 'search_failed'
    end

end
```

Comment: Yes, but the count triggers an extra unnecessary query!

Comment: That can't be caused by this code... since it renders either of the two 'search_fields', it's unpossible for the first if to be true and false, same goes for the second!

Comment: @SimoneCarletti the code does not have a bug, as the second I render the 'search_failed' page is used for cases where there is no input at all.

Comment: But if we get into details... you probably should handle this in the view! This is not what a controller should do...

Comment: You can of course use a separate partial to handle the use case of no results if you want to separate the code.

Comment: Yup, always remember: skinny controllers!